# Community Promotion Ads - 2016

Tags: discussion, community-ads

You've graduated, as per the new design received. It's somewhat overdue, but coming with your graduation is Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- interesting challenge and puzzle sites
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 x 250 pixels**, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- **If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.**

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/5044).

Comment: Traditionally, we would post a sample ad with the site's twitter, but unfortunately Puzzling does not have a twitter account. [Here's an example of one, though](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/704/community-promotion-ads-2016/705#705).

Comment: Out of curiosity, are Twitter pages normally created for SE sites?

Comment: We created them alongside site creation for a long time... up until Twitter started categorizing all of our new accounts as bots and suspending them. The amount of work needed just to unsuspend them was too much for the rate at which new sites were being generated, so we stopped making new Twitter accounts.

Comment: I don't see any pre-filled answer!

Comment: I think [this account](https://twitter.com/StackSciFi) is very active on Twitter.

Comment: @GraceNote - if an ad hits the 6 vote threshold, how long would it be before it was listed? Secondly, once listed, is there a way to remove it (eg. by deleting the answer here)? I ask because I have an idea for an ad, but it will only be relevant for the next week or two.

Comment: @Alconja The thread should be hooked up so once it hits the threshold it should be entered into the rotation shortly afterwards (caching and all that). And yes, if you delete it, it'll stop being shown - I might suggest posting a comment below the ad in this thread to indicate your intent to do such, just so that people are aware.

Answer (score 1):

[image: See all questions with active bounties]

Answer (score -2):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: Hey guys.  Please consider giving this an upvote; I want to deliver a quality product to you all week after week.

Comment: It's going to be hard for this not to come across as harsh, but I think it's an important question anyway (no offence is intended)... You don't really have any standing in this community. I.e. you haven't contributed any content, and therefore have no reputation to "trust". On top of that, we have no way of verifying the quality of the the product you're selling. So why should we, as a community, support your business with free advertising?

Comment: That's not harsh at all; it's a totally fair position to take.  I do regret not establishing myself here.  In fact I wanted to contribute content here to let you know the sort of puzzles you could expect, but Deusovi and I were talking about these plans and he let me know that I give up ownership of my IP if I post it here.  As someone starting out in this field, it's not a light move to make.  So I refrained, ultimately.

As far as trusting and supporting me, consider that there's no money in ripping you guys off.  Initial and constant low quality drives consumers away, and so doing the (c)

Comment: opposite is in my best interest as a business operator.  I've tried to create a worthwhile product and I aim to improve over time even if it's not "needed."  In my mind, businesses engaging with a particular community is all about a symbiotic relationship.  I deliver a product that hopefully enriches the community, and in turn the community financially compensates me.  If I can't help to enrich the community, then obviously I have to leave it by force.  I'm just asking for this initial chance.